# cross platform compilation and installers

Tags: c++, qt, installation

Assume you just wrote a Qt app. Write once compile everywhere...
you have a windows 7 x86 64 bits machine. You would like to:

1. Statically compile this executable ( to minimize the numbers of dll/so/frameworks )
2. Compile it for (x86_64, x86) * (windows[all],linux,mac, and why not bsd) = 6/8 couple (cpu,os)
3. You also would like people to perform the simplest possible installs:

   ```
               --> one file for installer which copies an sqlite database in program    data and an executable in program files
               --> linux via yum/yast/apt-get installs
               --> i'm not sure what to do for mac
   ```
4. simple uninstallers

How would you do all this from your windows machine, in particular cross compile for a mac ?

[Qt Installer Framework](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtifw-1.4/index.html) seems to be the right tool for the job. But I can't see how to compiler a mac binary anyway...

What would you use ? Any tool you often use ?

**EDIT**
following advice I'm looking for a cross compiler. I'll try to integrate it into Qt tool-chain... clang looks great.

1. http://blog.boceto.fr/2012/04/29/the-universal-compiler/
2. http://blog.boceto.fr/2012/05/07/the-universal-compiler-part-3-clang-targetting-mingw/
3. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html

Comment: @merlin09 there was I believe a typo in your edit.

Comment: I don’t think you can cross-compile for Mac on any other platform than Mac. Also, in general, managing the cross-compilers can be a lot  of work, and come with the drawback that you can’t run tests nor test the actual application at all. I’d rather work with VMs instead.

Comment: But with a VM you need to have a MAC os image, which is not free...

Comment: Yes, it's not free, and you can legally only run it on a MAC anyway, so it might as well not be a VM image :)

Comment: I think that while in theory what you want is doable, in practice setting up multiple hosts/VMs is much less work, and much better supported. That's why Qt's very own continuous integration system runs on multiple machines. When you cross compile like you wish, you'll be probably the only person on this planet to do so, and you'll end up supporting not only your own code, but also multiple toolchains. It's a lot of work for seemingly no discernible benefit. Get yourself a couple different (possibly virtual) hosts, a proper CI system, and it'll be easy going from there on.

Comment: You’ll need _some_ way to test your application under OS X anyway. “It cross-compiles, ship it!” won’t suffice. Same for Windows, you won’t get around buying at least one license for the respective operating systems.

Comment: I have a windows 7 64 bits desktop computer, a linux Lubuntu/Centos dual boot machine. So I can compile,run,test on windows and both apt and yum linux families. But I find very funny that in order to provide freeware to Mac OS, you must first hack them. I can always find someone to test it on a MAC for me. But I wont ask non technical people to compile it :). Anyway, maybe virtual machine is the way to go, even if it requires also separate installs of Qt tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to grab a [cross-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031453/way-cross-compile-c-c-code-to-run-on-windows-linux-and-mac-os), and just follow the steps indicated in the Qt Installer Framework for generating the installer executable, once for each platform.